# runtime rescheduling @scheduled cron expression without restarting app

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, quartz-scheduler

I have used scheduled annotation to schedule the task reading cronexpression from db. But when we change cron expression using UI , it needs to restart the app. How to inject `TaskScheduler` and `ScheduledFuture` or any other approach to reschedule without restarting when user update from UI which will call this method `updateTestJobSchedule` . Any example as per below code will be much helpful.

Currently i have : -

```
@Configuration
public class BasicConfig {

@Autowired
private TestJobSchedulerRepository testJobSchedulerRepository;

@Bean
public String getCronExpressionFromDb(){
    return testJobSchedulerRepository.findByIsActive(1).getCronExpression();
 }
}

@RestController
@EnableScheduling
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class TestJobController {


    @Scheduled(cron="#{getCronExpressionFromDb}")
    public void doTestJob(){
      // does the job
    }

    // This update cron expression when request comes from UI

  @RequestMapping(value = "/update-testjob-schedule_application",
  method = RequestMethod.POST,
  produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
   public ResponseEntity<String> updateTestJobSchedule(@RequestBody 
   TestJobScheduler testJobScheduler) throws URISyntaxException {

        if(testJobScheduler.getIsActive() == 0){
            testJobScheduler.setIsActive(1);
        } else{
            testJobScheduler.setIsActive(0);
        }
        testJobSchedulerRepository.save(testJobScheduler);
    return new ResponseEntity<>("{\"status\":\"success\"}", HttpStatus.OK);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to use the `TaskScheduler` object. The taskScheduler bean is automatically created when you have `@EnableScheduling` on a class annotated with `@Configuration`. This object can be used to schedule job on the fly. Here a quick exemple of what you can do with it :

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
public class CronJobConfiguration implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private TestJobSchedulerRepository testJobSchedulerRepository;

    @Autowired
    private TaskScheduler taskScheduler;

    @Override
    public void run(String... strings) {
        String cronExpression = testJobSchedulerRepository.findByIsActive(1).getCronExpression();
        Trigger trigger = new CronTrigger(cronExpression);
        ScheduledFuture scheduledFuture = taskScheduler
                .schedule(() -> {/* the job you want to run*/}, trigger);

        /* Keep the scheduledFuture to be able to cancel the job later Ex : */
        scheduledFuture.cancel(true);
    }
}
```

You'll probably need to keep the `ScheduledFuture` object returned by the schedule method to be able to cancel the job at some point. Also you'll need to have a service that use the `TaskScheduler` so that you can schedule job when the updateTestJobSchedule is called.

Comment: I have created a `@Component` service class where job is defined and calling into  lamda like this `taskScheduler.schedule(() -> {testJobService.doTestJob();}, trigger);`. I have defined method like this `@Override
    public Runnable doTestJob(){
        return () -> {// does the job};
    }` . But i could not get how to use `TaskScheduler` when `updateTestJobSchedule` is called. Could you please add sample code in above answer.

Comment: in the above comment service class i have used TaskScheduler.        `@Autowired private TaskScheduler taskScheduler;`
`ScheduledFuture<?> scheduledFuture; @Override`
    `public void reScheduleTestJob(String cronExpression) {`
        `Trigger trigger = new CronTrigger(cronExpression);`
        `taskScheduler.schedule(() -> { doTestJob(); }, trigger);`
        `scheduledFuture.cancel(true);  }`

    `@Override`
    `public void stopScheduler() {`
        `scheduledFuture.cancel(false); }` and calling from `updateTestJobSchedule`. But `doTestJob()` never called.